# JS reload/return again object values

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following:

```
var Module = (function() {
  
  var init = function() {

    var vars =  {
      topBar : ( $("#topbar").outerHeight() > 0 ) ? $("#topbar").outerHeight() : 0,
      header : $(".header").outerHeight()
    }

    // Recalculate values when window  is resized
    $(window).bind("resize", function() {
      vars;
    });

  });

})();

$(function() {
  Module.init();
});
```

I am trying to recalculate those variables when the window is resized but it is not working. Note: I have the maintain the function structures. I tried adding the variables outside but window resize is not picking them up

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
// Recalculate values when window  is resized
$(window).bind("resize", function() {
  vars;
});
```

In the above, the statement `vars;` doesn't actually do anything. You seem to be assuming it will recompute its value from the original initializer but that is not something that happens in javascript (or any other language that I am familiar with).

Instead you can extract out the initialization logic in a function and reuse it.

```
var Module = (function() {

function computeVars() {
    return {
      topBar : ( $("#topbar").outerHeight() > 0 ) ? $("#topbar").outerHeight() : 0,
      header : $(".header").outerHeight()
    };
}

 var vars =  computeVars();

  var init = function() {

    // Recalculate values when window  is resized
    $(window).bind("resize", function() {
      vars = computeVars();
    });

  });

})();

$(function() {
  Module.init();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Here. calling only `vars;` cant refresh the assigned data.
you have to calculate it again inside, or calling a function

```
var Module = (function() {
  
  var init = function() {

    var vars =  {
      topBar : ( $("#topbar").outerHeight() > 0 ) ? $("#topbar").outerHeight() : 0,
      header : $(".header").outerHeight()
    }

    // Recalculate values when window  is resized
    $(window).bind("resize", function() {
      //vars;
      vars =  {
       topBar : ( $("#topbar").outerHeight() > 0 ) ? $("#topbar").outerHeight() : 0,
       header : $(".header").outerHeight()
     }
    });

  });

})();

$(function() {
  Module.init();
});
```

Or You better do this.

```
var Module = (function() {
  
  var init = function() {

    var vars =  calculate_vars();

    var calculate_vars = ()=>{
        return  {
           topBar : ( $("#topbar").outerHeight() > 0 ) ? $("#topbar").outerHeight() : 0,
           header : $(".header").outerHeight()
        }
    }
    // Recalculate values when window  is resized
    $(window).bind("resize", function() {
      vars = calculate_vars();
    });

  });

})();

$(function() {
  Module.init();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
var Module = (function() { 
  init = function() {
    return {
      topBar : ( $("#topbar").outerHeight() > 0 ) ? $("#topbar").outerHeight() : 0,
      header : $(".header").outerHeight()
    }
  };
    $(window).bind("resize", function() {
      init();
    });
    return init;
})();

$(function() {
  Module()
});
```